# Open PDF at specific page using #page=n when serving file from PHP proxy

Tags: php, pdf, proxy

This seems like it should be simple. I have a set of files I have to store outside of the webroot and have an access script to call them. I also need to sometimes tell a PDF that must be called via this proxy script to open at a specific page. Releveant part of the script below:

```
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');

  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');

  readfile($file);
```

$file_name is just the basename() of the file, and $file is the path to the file, with #page=2, or #page=10, or whatever appended to it. If I remove the hashtag portion, the script works fine and the PDF opens with no errors. When the hashtag portion is there, all the programs tell me the PDF has been corrupted and can't be open. 
I can't seem to find anything on here or Google as to what I need to do. Do I need to set an additional header to simulate the hash tag? Use exec() to call some command line code instead of using readfile()?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append the #page=2 (or whatever page you want to open) to the URL in the browser, not the filename in the proxy-script.

You currently try to open a file `myFile.pdf#page=2` from the filesystem that does not exist as the filename is `myFile.pdf`

The feature to open a pdf-file on a specific page on the other hand is implemented in the browser or it's PDF-plugin. Therefore the information which page to open has to be given to the browser via the URL. So you should call your proxyscript like this: http://example.com/proxy.php?myFile.php#page=2

**Update:**

If you want to download the file and open it at a specific page every time the file is opened from the local file-system of the user, you will have to edit (or recreate) the PDF-File.

Comment: Hm must be a problem with my proxy then because that's what I tried first and it ignored it. Totally works with a "normal" pdf link. Wonder if it has to do with the fact that the link appears normal (/foo/bar.pdf) which is .htaccess rewritten to the foo-proxy.php script

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted anyway, now to figure out why the hash isn't being passed to the proxy script via URL

Comment: You can find the open-parameters at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf. But beware. Not all clients (or their plugins) understand that as the API is from Adobe. Oh, and perhaps you should change your header "Content-Disposition" to "inline".

Comment: What do you know, both of your suggestions combined fixed it. Thank you!